# MongoDb "left join" with different column types

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections: User and UserProfile.

UserProfile references User by the property userId as UUID.

User collection have _id field but as string.

How can I "left join" these two collections to find out what documents don't have a match?

Here is what I got so far:

```
db.UserProfile.aggregate({
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'User',
       localField: 'userId', // this is UUID
       foreignField: '_id', // this is string
       as: 'user'
     }
})
```

Here are two sample entities:

```
User:
{
    "_id" : "0c7e18b2-3682-444d-a62b-30e311e76891",
    "userName" : "programad",
    "normalizedUserName" : "PROGRAMAD",
    "email" : "programad@gmail.com",
    "normalizedEmail" : "PROGRAMAD@GMAIL.COM",
    "emailConfirmed" : true,
    "concurrencyStamp" : "56d3d071-0e30-458a-880a-ed75e20863a9",
    "lockoutEnabled" : true,
    "roles" : [ ],
    "claims" : [ ],
    "logins" : [ ],
    "tokens" : [ ],
    "recoveryCodes" : [ ]
}

UserProfile:
{
    "_id" : UUID("a4d5b6d5-f181-4267-5b81-08d64d02d681"),
    "userId" : UUID("0c7e18b2-3682-444d-a62b-30e311e76891"),
    "createDate" : ISODate("2018-08-01T00:00:00.000-03:00"),
    "type" : "Personal",
    "name" : "Daniel Gomes",
    "motto" : "Code Lover",
    "bio" : "bio yadda yadda",
    "studioName" : "My studio name",
    "location" : "Santos/Brazil",
    "externalLinks" : [ ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a gentleman called **Vignan Yarlagadda** helped me on this.

I needed to find wich profiles lack users or vice-versa.

He came around with this:

```
db.UserMissing.drop();
var cur = db.UserProfile.find({"_id":{"$exists":1}}).addOption(16);
cur.forEach(function(x){
    db.UserMissing.insert({"_id":x.userId,"userId":x.userId})
});
var cur = db.User.find({"_id":{"$exists":1}}).addOption(16);
cur.forEach(function(x){
 var string=x._id;
 var y=UUID(string);
 db.UserProfile.find({"userId":y}).forEach(function(doc){
     db.UserMissing.update({"userId":doc.userId},{"$set":{"Matching":true}},{"multi":true});

 });
});
db.UserMissing.find({"Matching":{"$exists":0}});


It creates **a temporary collection** called UserMissing and I can see witch ones to focus my attention.
```